# Wave problem $u_{tt}=u_{xx}-u_t, 0\le x\le 2\pi$ with $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$, $u_t(x,0)=\psi(x)$ and $u(0,t)=u(2\pi,t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, alternative-proof, wave-equation

Solve the wave problem $$\begin{cases}u_{tt}=u_{xx}-u_t, 0\le x\le 2\pi\\ u(0,t)=u(2\pi,t)=0\\ u(x,0)=\phi(x)\\ u_t(x,0)=\psi(x)\end{cases}$$ Write the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions explicitly.

Are they orthogonal?

We propose the separated solution $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$.

Then $\frac{(T''+T')}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}=\lambda$.

If we define $\lambda=\beta^2,$  we have $X(x)=C\cos\beta x+D\sin\beta x$ and $T(t)=Ae^{r_1t}+Be^{r_2t}, r=-1/2\pm\frac{\sqrt{1+4\beta^2}}{2}$.

Applying boundary condition, we find that $X_n(x)=D_n\sin(\lambda_nx),\lambda=\sqrt{n/2}$

Applying initial conditions we find that $T(0)=A+B=\phi(x)$ and $T'(0)=Ar_1+Br_2=\psi(x)$

My question here is how will I find $A$ and $B$ if we don't know $\phi$ nor $\psi$ ?

How will I find the eigenvalues ?

Help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boundary conditions give

$$ X(x) = \sin\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right) $$

As usual, we drop the remaining constant for now, since it'll absorbed into the constants of $T(t)$

This means $\lambda_n = X''/X = -n^2/4 = -\beta^2$ (you have a sign error). The other equation becomes

$$ T'' + T' + \frac{n^2}{4}T = 0 $$

The two roots of the characteristic are

$$ r = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-n^2}}{2} $$

Since $n \ge 1$, we rewrite

$$ r = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-(n^2-1)}}{2} = \frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{n^2-1}}{2} $$

This gives the solution

$$ T(t) = e^{-t/2}\left[A\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}{2}t\right) + B\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}{2}t\right) \right] $$

For ease of notation, let $\mu_n = \sqrt{n^2-1}$ to make things shorter, so we have

\begin{align} T(t) &= e^{-t/2}\left[A\cos\left(\frac{\mu}{2}t\right) + B\sin\left(\frac{\mu}{2}t\right) \right] \\
T'(t) &= e^{-t/2}\left[\left(-\frac{A}{2} + \frac{\mu B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\mu}{2}t\right) + \left(-\frac{B}{2} - \frac{\mu A}{2} \right)\sin \left(\frac{\mu}{2}t\right) \right] \end{align}

As usual, the full solution in series form is

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_n X_n(x)T_n(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right) e^{-t/2}\left[A\cos\left(\frac{\mu}{2}t\right) + B\sin\left(\frac{\mu}{2}t\right) \right] $$

We can now plug in the given initial conditions

\begin{align} u(x,0) &= \sum_n X_n(x)T_n(0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \sin\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right) = \phi(x) \\
u_t(x,0) &= \sum_n X_n(x){T_n}'(0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{A_n}{2} + \frac{\mu B_n}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right) = \psi(x)
\end{align}

You'll need to find the Fourier series of these to functions to obtain the coefficients

\begin{align}
B_n &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \phi(x) \sin\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right) dx \\
\frac{-A_n + \mu B_n}{2} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \psi(x) \sin\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right) dx
\end{align}

and solve the resulting system of equations. There's no specific form for the solution here, but you'll know what to do when you are given specific $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, i.e. just do the integrals.

Comment: The 'explicit' eigenfunction of T(t) is $A\cos(\frac{\mu}{2}t)+B\sin(\frac{\mu}{2}t)$  and the eigenvalue is $\mu_n = \sqrt{n^2-1}$?

Comment: And I could add a comment saying that A and B can be found if one solves the system $\begin{align}
B_n &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \phi(x) \sin\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right) dx \\
\frac{-A_n + \mu B_n}{2} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \psi(x) \sin\left(\frac{n}{2}x\right) dx
\end{align}$ for $A_n$ and $B_n$, right?

Comment: No, the eigenvalue is still $\lambda$, and the eigenfunction is all of $T(t)$, including the exponential part. For the second question, yes, assuming the RHS expressions are known.

Comment: I don't see why is still $\lambda$, I though the eigenvalues for $X$ and $T$ are different. Yes the eigenfunctions of $T(t)$ include the exponential part (my typo in the comment above).

Comment: No, they shouldn't be different, that's kind of the rationale for using separation of variables, i.e. setting two functions to be equal to the same constant. Remember the equation for $T$ is $$ T'' + T' = \lambda T $$ This is in the form of $$ \mathcal L(T) = \lambda T $$ where $\mathcal L $ is a linear operator.

Comment: oh ok Dylan, I have a question about the orthogonality, how do I check if they are orthogonal? I know that $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal if $\int f\cdot g=0.$ In this case what is the integral? Is this what needs to be integrated $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\frac{n}{2}x) e^{-t/2}[A_n\cos (\frac{\mu}{2}t) + B_n\sin(\frac{\mu}{2}t) ]$  and to see if it's equal to 0?

Comment: I've just saw your last comment on the other answer (And I wonder why you don't use @Dylan so you get a notification)... so I am wrong or maybe not. In the question just says _Are the orthogonal?_ but how do you know that is asking orthogonality like this $X\cdot X$ and not like this $X\cdot T$?

Comment: @Isa Orthogonal functions need to exist in the same space. It doesn't make sense for a function of $x$ and a function of $t$ to be orthogonal to each other. They need to be integrated over the same domain. I would suggest you look in your text for similar examples instead of asking me so many questions.

Comment: I did look in the book, I saw something like  $\int f\cdot g=0$ and as I saw different functions I thought immediately about orthogonality between different functions, i.e. $X$  and $T$ but did not realize until now about the integration over the same domain $dx$. I apologize for bothering you asking so many questions . Anyway I think this is the last time that I ask a question about PDE on mse :) since my course finish today.

Comment: It's all good. I'm bothered by all the questions, just wanted to check all bases. Anyway, orthogonality requires $ \int_0^L X_n(x)X_m(x)\ dx $ equals $0$ for $m \ne n$, and equals some constant for $m=n$. You should be able to check that this is true for $X_n = \sin(nx/2) $

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong when you say $T(0)=\phi(x)$. We actually have $$\phi(x)=\sum_n(A_n+B_n)\sin(nx/2)$$ and $$\psi(x)=\sum_n(A_n r_1+B_nr_2)\sin(nx/2)$$
In principle, this can be inverted, using orthogonality of $\sin (nx)$ to find the constants $A_n$ and $B_n$. This is done, say, by multiplying both sides by $\sin(mx/2)$ and summing over $m$.

Comment: I do not see why am I wrong. I just applied the same method for $X(0)$ in $T(0)$. $T(t)=Ae^{r_1t}+Be^{r_2t}$, thus $T(0)=A+B=\phi(x)$. Why are you applying this condition $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$ ?

Comment: If I multiply both sides by $\sin(mx/2)$ and sum over m, would that be zero?

Comment: Could you write more details please, I don't get it. How to find the constants?

Comment: We only have boundary conditions for $X(x)$ because they are homogeneous, i.e. $X(0)T(t) =0, \forall t \implies X(0) = 0$ and so on. This does doesn't work for the two initial conditions since they are non-zero

Comment: Also, $T(0)$ is a constant and shouldn't depend on $x$, so it makes no sense to begin with.

Comment: @Isa the condition given in the question is $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$, which is what I used. Also, see Dylan's second comment - $T(0)$ is not a function of $X$. As for what happens when you sum after multiplication by $\sin(mx/2)$, you need to use that $\sin(mx/2)\sin(nx/2)=\alpha \delta_{m,n}$ where $\alpha$ is some normalisation constant coming from the orthogonality relation for this particular basis, (which you can find) and $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.

Comment: @Isa I think there's no longer any need to add details, since Dylan's answer does this. Where he said "you'll need to find the Fourier series of these functions", I have used the orthogonality of $\sin$ as described above. Both methods give the same end result, where you have two equations for the constants $A_n$ and $B_n$. I think he found that the normalisation constant $\alpha=1/\pi$ (but you should check this, I haven't read it in too much detail)

Comment: [My answer for this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804627/solve-the-laplace-equation-u-xx-u-yy-0-inside-the-square-0-leq-x-le/2805271#comment5784514_2805271) addresses the orthogonality and why the formula is what it is. But in short the normalization is just $\int_0^L X^2(x)dx = L/2$ where $L=2\pi$